# Modal in child frame should appear on top of overlay which is in parent frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on the bootstrap modal. Currently, my scenario is as follows. I have a parent frame which has some n nested frames. From nth child frame, I want to open a modal but the overlay should disable actions in the whole window. I tried opening modal in child and overlay in the parent. But being an overlay in the parent window, it is disabling me to perform actions in my modal window. Can someone please help me out.

I want either the overlay in child1.html should occupy the whole parent.html

or

The modal opening in child1.html should be on top of overlay which I can add in parent.html

**parent.html**

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<frameset rows="5%,95%">

<frame src="child.html"></frame>

<frame src="child1.html"></frame>

</frameset>

</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

**child1.html**

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">


  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how do yo create an overlay in parent?

Comment: I tried creating a div as follows `<div id="overlay" class="modal-backdrop fade">` and added a handler to modal in child1.html. On opening of modal, the overlay in child1.html will get hidden and the overlay in parent.html will be displayed. I know this kind will disable modal window editing but still I need to know whether is there any chance to crack this.

Comment: the thing is that you don't have body when using `frameset`, so can't use a `div ` in parent

Comment: Okay can we make an overlay to appear on top if the same parent.html is in an iframe of ancestor.html as follows: `<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
 <iframe src="parent.html" width="100%" height="100%">
</body>

</html>`

Comment: check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/EELb74Lw1fwMJMjlDthB?p=preview)